# how to clone url parameter value inside img src attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url-parameters

I am trying to get parameter value from the url, add it inside a div and then clone that value inside the img src attribute.

I can get the parameter value inside a div, and get it to clone as well but it's doing it like this:

`<img id="target" src="images/">samplevalue.png</img>`

I need to do like it this:

`<img id="target" src="images/samplevalue.png" />`

Sample parameter: `param1=samplevalue.png`

here's the code:

**html**

```
<div id="block1"></div>
<img id="target" src=""/>
```

**jQuery/Javascript**

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1].replace(/\+/g, "&nbsp"));
        }
    }
    return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
}

document.getElementById("block1").innerHTML = 
getQueryVariable("param1");

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img#target").attr("src", "images/").html($("#block1").html());
});
```

Even if adding the parameter value straight inside the img src attribute is fine too than adding first inside the div.

Any help on this is highly appreciated. 
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Part of the problem is because you're setting `html()` on an `img` element, which is invalid. Don't do that.

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan. I understood your information all I'll make sure about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the returned value from the function as part of the attribute `src`.

With `.html($("#block1").html())` on the image element, you are trying to set html on th image which is actually invalid:

Change the function to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var urlPart = getQueryVariable();
  $("img#target").attr("src", "images/" + urlPart);
});
```

**Please Note:**

Since you are already using jQuery, I will suggest you not to mix JavaScript & jQuery if possible, like:

```
document.getElementById("block1").innerHTML = getQueryVariable("param1");
```

Could be easily written:

```
$('#block1').text(getQueryVariable("param1")); //text() is preferred when dealing with text content
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Mamun and for vital information. It helped me to understand it better and also thank you for the update. Have a great day bro :)

Comment: also thanks @Rory for pointing it out :) and have a great day bro :)

Comment: Thank you once again @Mamun for updating the answer and making the code more efficient bro :)

Comment: @pv619, glad that it makes sense to you :)

Answer (score 4):

You should do it like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var param1 = getQueryVariable("param1");
    $("img#target").attr("src", "images/"+param1);
    $("#block1").html(param1);  
});
```

Put your param into a variable and then use it to change your SRC attribute and to put the content into your div.

Comment: Thank you for the help bro. It resolved my issue and have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("img#target").attr("src", "images/"+$("#block1").html());
```

Comment: You may want to test this as you're setting HTML *within* an `img` tag, which is invalid.

Comment: Thank you @evgeni for your answer and have a great day :)